Symmetric functions and pattern avoidance
It is known that the number of $k$-regular simple graphs with vertices labeled by $1,2,\dots,n$ can be expressed as the coefficient of $x_1^k \dots x_n^k$ in a symmetric function, which is
$$
\prod_{1\leq i<j \leq n}(1+x_ix_j).
$$
Using this representation and tools from the theory of symmetric functions, the recursive formula for this enumeration problem can be derived much more easily than by a pure combinatorial approach (see [1] and [2] for 4-regular graphs).
Now consider the same enumeration problem except that the graphs are not allowed to contain a certain pattern, such as triangles or 4-cycles. Are there any works in the literature where this number can be expressed in terms of symmetric functions, in such a way that one can compute the number effectively?
[1] I. P. Goulden, D. M. Jackson, and J. W. Reilly, The Hammond Series of a Symmetric Function and Its Application to P-Recursiveness, 1983.
[2] R. C. Read, N. C. Wormald, Number of labeled 4-regular graphs, 1980.

Can you add some references? As it is stated now, it is of course clear that such a function in principle exists.

If we put each $x_i=1$ in $\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(1-x_ix_j)$, then we obtain $2^{{n\choose 2}}$, the total number of simple graphs with vertices $1,2,\dots,n$. What would the analogue be for triangle-free ,graphs, say? The total number of simple triangle-free graphs with vertices $1,2,\dots,n$? But no reasonable expression is known for this number. This suggests that the symmetric function approach to counting triangle-free graphs is not going to be successful.
